Is etymology more flexible than some assert?
I hope I can explain this, and I will try with an example: The word "see" and "seem" I read are unrelated even though one could very plausibly assume that they are very related.
But does it not matter what people who use the word think? If someone uses "seem" and they perceive this similarity, how do we know that the word did not arise at different times and different places, and in some of those places, "seem" indeed arose as a variant of "see" -- perhaps a stranger used the word and it only was adopted because the group saw "seem" as related to "see"?
I am concerned with the specific example, only that the way a new word is adopted in a group of speakers might differ and one group understood the origins differently.
I hope this makes some sense. I guess my main point is, how do we know a word has a single, definite origin? In this example, if some people understood "seem" as being related to "see", how can it be said they were wrong?

Words can definitely have more than one single, definite origin – that’s not uncommon at all, and etymological dictionaries generally note when this is the case. We can’t rule out, of course, that some people at some point have grown up thinking that seem was a variant of see, and it’s possible that this has even influenced the use of the word, changing its meaning from ‘befit, behoove’ to just ‘appear, look like’. But that doesn’t change the fact that when it first entered English, it was just a loan from Old Norse (where sjá and sœma are clearly unrelated).

I'd say mainstream etymology is well aware of this phenomenon.
"influenced by": https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?search=%22influenced+by%22&title=Special:Search&profile=advanced&fulltext=1&ns0=1
"by analogy": https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?search=%22by+analogy%22&title=Special:Search&profile=advanced&fulltext=1&ns0=1
"contaminated with": https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?search=%22contaminated+with%22&title=Special:Search&profile=advanced&fulltext=1&ns0=1

But that's all just the actual etymology. Complexity in the details of an etymology doesn't mean that it's "flexible".

That's not considered "flexibility" so much as just, part of how etymology works!
A lot of books and courses on historical linguistics start with the Neogrammarian hypothesis, the idea that sound changes are regular and exceptionless, applying to sounds instead of words, and any exceptions need to be explained with more rules. This is a pretty solid model, and it's laid the foundations for historical linguistics as a proper discipline.
But it's not the full story. Soon you'll get to analogy and contamination (like the connection between "seem" and "see") and other processes that aren't regular and exceptionless. And these are important, because without them you can't explain the etymology of plenty of common words!
And eventually you'll discover wave models (as opposed to tree models) which say, even when we're talking about regular sound change, it might not apply to the entire language and the entire population at once. We might need to think about how exactly the change spreads from person to person and word to word instead of abstracting that away.
But this isn't etymology being flexible, really; there's still an actual historical truth behind how a particular word came about, after all. It's just that there are different levels of abstraction we can analyze it at.
